# format REST response on client

Tags: javascript, client-side-scripting

is there a standard established way to do the following:

curl -i "http://api.waqi.info/feed/shanghai/?token=demo"

returns

{
   status: "ok",
   data: {
      aqi: 70,
      time: {
         s: "2016-12-11 12:00:00"
      },
      city: {
         name: "Shanghai",
         url: "http://aqicn.org/city/shanghai/",
         geo: [
            "31.2047372",
            "121.4489017"
         ]
      },
      iaqi: {
         pm25: "..."
      }
   }
}

i want to make a simple page that calls the API and formats the result.  but i want to do it in the browser so that i can host a serverless webpage.

Ive look at Angular and react but it seems an awful lot of setup and baggage to do something simple like this.

i could write the jscript and html from scratch but also feels like there should be some libraries to support this.

Comment: Try using [`fetch() API`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API). Note that remote endpoint will need to be CORS enabled in order to make request directly from browser without using a server side proxy

Comment: are asking for a HTTP client library like [axiois](https://github.com/axios/axios)

Comment: @charlietfl thanks. so i can use fetch to get the json.. but then i still need to format it.  I can write more code to format the json but I was hoping there was just a shrink-wrapped way to do this...  ie take the json and put it in a table

Comment: There are template libraries like  handlebars.js or mustache.js you can use or is very common to parse to html (or dom nodes) yourself

Answer (score 0):

You can write an ajax call to get the data like this:

```
fetch('http://api.waqi.info/feed/shanghai/?token=demo')
  .then(function(response) {
    return response.json();
  })
  .then(function(jsonData) {
    console.log(jsonData); //the data you want to get
  });
```

More information [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch)

If you want to use some library, you can try [superagent](https://github.com/visionmedia/superagent)

Comment: So basically you fetch JSON content and JSON.Parse it to access the nodes by name. Have a look at https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_objects.asp

Comment: so i was hoping there was super lightweight framework already for doing this.. i know i can use ajax and format myself.. i just don't want to.   i need to do 1% of what angular will give me.. so want that without the baggage..

Answer (score 0):

I have used `jQuery` plugin and used `$.ajax()` method: See [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/ajax_ajax.asp).

Later, I split all data using `keys` as shown below;

```js
$.ajax({
 url: 'http://api.waqi.info/feed/shanghai/?token=demo',
  success: function(ajax) {
   console.log(ajax);
   let data         = ajax.data;         // Object
    let api          = data.api;          // Int
    let attributions = data.attributions; // Array [3]
    let cityCoords   = data.city.geo;     // Array [2]
    let cityName     = data.city.name;    // String
    let cityUrl      = data.city.url;     // String 
    let dominentpol  = data.dominentpol; // String
    let iaqi         = data.iaqi;         // Object Keys = [co, d, h, no2, o3, p ,pm10, pm25, so2, t, w, wd]
    let idx          = data.idx;          // Int
    let time         = data.time;         // Object Keys = [s, tz, v]
    let status       = ajax.status;
    
    console.log("Data Object: " 
    + data + 
    "\nAPI Version: " 
    + api + 
    "\nAttributions #1 Name: " 
    + attributions[0].name +
    "\nAttributions #1 Url: " 
    + attributions[0].url +
    "\nAttributions #2 Name: " 
    + attributions[1].name +
    "\nAttributions #2 Url: " 
    + attributions[1].url +
    "\nAttributions #3 Name: " 
    + attributions[2].name +
    "\nAttributions #3 Url: " 
    + attributions[2].url +
    "\nCity Longitude: "
    + cityCoords[0] +
    "\nCity Latitude: "
    + cityCoords[1] +
    "\nCity Name: "
    + cityName +
    "\nCity Url: "
    + cityUrl +
    "\dDominentpol: "
    + dominentpol +
    "\nIaqi Key [co]: "
    + iaqi.co +
    "\nIaqi Key [d]: "
    + iaqi.d +
    "\nIaqi Key [h]: "
    + iaqi.h +
    "\nIaqi Key [no2]: "
    + iaqi.no2 +
    "\nIaqi Key [o3]: "
    + iaqi.o3 +
    "\nIaqi Key [p]: "
    + iaqi.p +
    "\nIaqi Key [pm10]: "
    + iaqi.pm10 +
    "\nIaqi Key [pm25]: "
    + iaqi.pm25 +
    "\nIaqi Key [so2]: "
    + iaqi.so2 +
    "\nIaqi Key [t]: "
    + iaqi.t +
    "\nIaqi Key [w]: "
    + iaqi.w +
    "\nIaqi Key [wd]: "
    + iaqi.wd +
    "\nIdx: "
    + idx +
    "\nTime Key = [s]: "
    + time.s +
    "\nTime Key = [tz]:"
    + time.tz +
    "\nTime Key = [v]:"
    + time.v +
    "\nStatus: "
    + status);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```